# Unable to type in Ninja Forms textbox

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have used ninja forms on this [website](http://www.keyaccountmanagement.org/customise-this-site-for-my-company/) and I am unable to type in the text box.

Tried making a new form, in a new page etc however its still not working?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is caused by one of the javascript files. Disabling javascript  allow you to type into the text boxes.

Comment: The last `input` box in your form is working as expected, all the other inputs have a `data-input-limit` attribute, my guess is this will be your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was being caused by the Jasny Bootstrap Script - not the two that were shown in the firebug console. 
I corrected this by customising the jasny downloading before compiling and then running the minimised script on the site and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I was running version 2.9 and found a simple fix - I went into settings for Ninja Forms and at the bottom, it asks if you want to update to version 3.0. I never saw any notification to update anywhere else, on the plugins page, dashboard, etc.

So I updated it and it works perfectly now. Strange that they would bury an update in the settings page.